# OAuth2 authorization server with claims

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model

I have a Web API application and I want to secure that. I've been reading about ThinkTectures IdentityModel and IdentityServer for authorization (OAtuh2) and I think this is what I need.

I'm just not really sure where to start with this. There are so many solutions available that I'm not sure what to use.

I think I need to add `ThinkTecture.IndentityModel` to my Web API application right?

Should I then download `ThinkTecture.IdentityServer2`? Or do I need `Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer` as well? I'm kinda confused there.

In the end I want my Web API application to be able to login into a identity server which returns claims that belongs to that user.

Could anyone tell me where and how to start with this. I need a push in the right direction.

For starters I already added `ThinkTecture.IndentityModel` to my WEB Api application. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest starting with the wikis of each project. They go into details about the purpose of each project and how to get started:

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer/wiki

Comment: Ok I started with *Identity Server 2* since I think it fits my needs best. The only thing I can´t really figure out is how to work with `claims`. Is it possible to assign custom `claims` to users, like I can with `roles`? Is this possible right out of the box? Or do I have to make a custom implementation to assign claims to users? Any info/blog/tutorial about this is more than welcome. Since I couldn't really find anything useful.

Comment: Yes, you can assign custom claims to users. IdentityServer has extensibility points for emitting those custom claims in the token. Again, check the wiki.